# I accidentally ran sudo upgrade-from-legacy-grub

Tags: boot, grub2, network-manager, grub-legacy, rescue-mode

I messed up my pc and I'm stuck in grub recovery mode

Heres what happened:

1. I was upgrading from 20.04 to 22.--; but i left halfway after doing sudo update & upgrade-distro and didn't download the 2 gigs of packages
2. I installed mopidy with apt manager but then idk somehow my wifi disconnected and nmcli and networkManager had disappeared
3. I ran sudo upgrade-from-legacy-grub, idk why and restarted to find that grub booted into recovery mode

basically I'm having 2 issues right now

In recovery mode it says it cannot find normal.mod, neither can I anywhere on my pc

I tried running insmod linux, but same result, it cannot find such file

tldr: I ran `sudo upgrade-from-legacy-grub` and now I'm stuck with grub recovery mode. Before that my nmcli had disappeared randomly

Comment: Language please .. 

Comment: Please edit your question with correct details. None of the commands you put in your question are real/valid commands. It's difficult to help if we are working with incorrect information. Please edit your question and make an effort to be accurate. Surely you'd want the same in an answer. Help us help you.

Comment: Since you messed something completely up and are not even able to give us correct information I'd recommend a fresh install. You are for sure not a linux expert, nothing wrong with that. Instead of spending hours or even days trying to repair your broken system doing a fresh install will lead you to a working system in much less time.

Comment: Most systems are now UEFI (grub-efi-amd64), some are still BIOS (grub-pc), but grub-legacy has not been used for about 15 years. Installing  that probably corrupted whatever version of grub you really were using. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/